# error: '.class' expected

Tags: java, class

Hi friends while compiling the  below error is coming

error: '.class' expected

I'm not able to find what is the error. I checked in many websites but not able to find why this error is coming. Plz Help

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;

class Test
{
    boolean isGoodEmployee(boolean ismarried,int noofchild,String middlename,String childnames[])
    {
        boolean child,letter,last,child;

        if (noofchild <= 2)
            child=true;
        boolean firstletter = middlename.startsWith("k");
        boolean lastletter = middlename.endssWith("e");

        if (firstletter && (!lastletter))
            letter = true;

        int lastnameletterscount = lastname.length();

        if (lastnameletterscount > 4)
            last = true;

        String name = raju;

        for (int i=0; i < noofchild; i++)
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(childnames[i]))
            {
                child = true;
                break;
            }
    }
}


class GoodEmployee
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String firstname, middlename, lastname;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter the first name of employee");
        firstname = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("enter the middle name of employee");
        middlename = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("enter the last name of employee");
        lastname = br.readLine();
        //System.out.println("full name of employee is:"+first+middle+last);
        System.out.println("enter employee is married or not");
        boolean ismarried = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());

        if (ismarried)
            System.out.println("enter number of childrens");

        int noofchild = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String childnames[] = new String[noofchild];
        System.out.println("enter children names");

        for (int i=0; i < noofchild; i++)
            childnames[i] = br.readLine();
        Test t = new Test();
        t.isGoodEmployee(ismarried,noofchild,middlename,childnames[]);
    }
}
```

I'm using "javac GoodEmployee.java" to compile the program

Comment: Please indent your code, it's very difficult to read!!

Comment: Please output the full error

Comment: Please include in your question the exact command that you are using to compile the file. You are not e.g. using `java` instead of `javac` to compile, right?

Comment: @StephenC : How can u mark this (which was asked around 5 years back) to a question added 3 days back. I believe that should be duplicate. Before marking and highlighting ur question check the asked dates

Comment: I did check your question before marking it as a dup.   The dates are **irrelevant**.

Comment: @StephenC : Then ur question is duplicate. As u didn't checked this question before asking same type of question. Anyway enjoy duplicating.

Comment: I have tried to explain this to you, but failed.  I suggest that you ask a question on meta.stackoverflow.com, and someone else can explain to you why creation of questions to be dup targets is a good thing, not a bad thing.

Answer (score 4):

You have a mis-matching method call in `isGoodEmployee`.

The `childnames` argument is defined as an array, so you can simply pass in the argument, replace:

```
t.isGoodEmployee(ismarried,noofchild,middlename,childnames[]);
```

with

```
t.isGoodEmployee(ismarried,noofchild,middlename,childnames);
```

Aside from that, do not ignore other compilers errors such as

```
middlename.endssWith("e");
               ^---------extra 's'
```

Familiarize yourself with the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 1):

there's plenty wrong with this code:
you've declared boolean child twice in isGoodEmployee() (1st line)
endssWith should be endsWith() 
and so on, but nont of them are the issue you stated. what command line are you using for compiling this class?

Answer (score 0):

@Reimeus has nailed it.

The strange compilation error can be explained as follows.  In this line:

```
 t.isGoodEmployee(ismarried,noofchild,middlename,childnames[]);
```

the `childnames[]` phrase is supposed to be a Java expression.  But in fact, the syntax most closely resembles a type ... in fact an array of some (non-existent) class called `childnames`.  The Java compiler's syntax error recovery code has decided that if it inserts `.class` after the typename (i.e. `childnames[].class`) that will give a syntactically valid expression.

Of course, the correction that the compiler is suggesting is nonsensical ... not least because there won't be a class or interface named `childnames` in your application.

---

The moral of the story is that unusual syntax errors sometimes cause a compiler to produce peculiar error messages that only make sense if you can figure out how the parser would have parsed the erroneous input.

Answer (score 0):

Make the class with the main method public if you are using an IDE.
In case you are trying to run it using command window I don't think a '.class' file is required for compiling rather it would be required for execution. So after you have a .class file by entering javac GoodEmployee and you have no errors enter java GoodEmployee which will execute the .class file you have.